# How to store specific column values from a table using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table in my application and table having some columns and rows . I want to store all the values from a particular column . Could some one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First, we identify each cell as a searchable element:

```
public IWebElement row1 => driver.findElement(By.Id("");
public IWebElement row2 => driver.findElement(By.Id("");
```

Next we create placeholders for the strings each cell contains:

```
public static string row1Val;
public static string row2Val;
```

Next, we need a method to get text and store in the placeholders:

```
public string GetCellValue(IWebElement id)
    {
        IWebElement Cell = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
        string value = Cell.Text;
        return value;
    }
```

Finally, we loop over the table and grab all of the values:

```
public void GetAllTableValues()
    {
        row1Val = GetCellValue(row1);
        row2Val = GetCellValue(row2);
    {
```